# Can IOTA be made private and fungible?

Tags: privacy

Opt-in privacy is flawed in blockchain coins as you can differentiate the private transaction from other transactions—breaking fungibility. Does this hold true for IOTA since it works differently than a typical blockchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be able to differentiate an IOTA transaction that has been run through a mixer / tumbler to hide it's past. The only way for this not to be true is if privacy is not opt-in, which IOTA does not currently do or plan to do.